# autoload function not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3

in application/config/config.php file I have added this autoload code for model

```
function __autoload($class) {
 if (file_exists(APPPATH."models/".strtolower($class).EXT)) {
    include_once(APPPATH."models/".strtolower($class).EXT);
 }
}
```

to autoload model

and I am using model in controller like this

```
public function index()
{
    $post = new post();
}
```

but it is showing error
Class 'post' not found

I do have post model in model folder already created

I am using the autoload code from source
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters--net-8308

but it is not working like shown in blog.
Do I need anything else to update more for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to autoload a model in your CI3 app, just go in application/config/autoload.php and find the line :

```
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

Then, add the model you want to autoload :

```
$autoload['model'] = array('my_model', 'my_second_model');
```

Then in your controller, you don't need to create a new instance of your model class. Example :

```
$res = $this->my_model->myfunction();
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion I know this one, but I want to use model as shown in reference link

Comment: @user3232286 Your link is for CodeIgniter 1.7.2 which is more than old and, you are on CI3.

Comment: _autoload function is php function and it does not depend on codeigniter, it is just for reference

Comment: I know that, it's just I don't get why you want to do this that way. That was usefull at that time, not now. I'll delete my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Use capital letter for your class name.
Btw. I agree with first answer.